# How can i free memory in this case?

Tags: c++

I have the following code. My program has a base class, that is **c1**. **c2** and **c3** are its derived classes. I also have a class called **FilmDB**(database), which stores all my films in one array, which name is **films**. In these if statements, i put the films into this array, depending on its type. (test condition). It works just fine, however **f**, **cs**, **d** will never be free, memory leaking comes. The problem is that i can not use delete [] within the if statement, because my program crashes, but i cant use it outside, because f, cs, d are not visible there as I see. Memtrace shows leak because of **f**, **cs**, and **d**.

```
if(test == "a"){
            Class2 *c2 = new Class2(param1,param2,param3,param4);
            films[i] = c2;
        }


        else if(test == "b"){
            Class3 *c3 = new Class3(param1,param2,param3,param4);
            films[i] = c3;
        }


        else {
            Class1 *c1 = new Class1(param1,param2,param3);
            films[i] = c1;
        }
```

My FilmDB class has a virtual destructor which iterates the array and delete it, but it does not seem to solve my problem.

```
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
       delete films[i];
```

**EDIT FROM COMMENT:**

I am not allowed to use `std::vector` in my task

Comment: You should use _std::vector_ and avoid the use of _delete_ in C++

Comment: provide a proper question. We can;t understand from this.

Comment: Do `Csaladi`, `Dokumentum` and `Film` have common base class? Does that class has virtual destructor? Is `filmcount` a correct value?

Comment: Film is the base class, Csaladi and Dokumentum are the derived ones. I tried to edit my code to make it more understandable.

Comment: Run your code in a debugger and find the crash. There is no earthly way we can proffer anything but wags (wild-arse-guesses) that we could offer reasons for why that happens, as you have nothing even remotely resembling a [minimum, **complete**, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reproduces your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you reusing the index of films[i] at all?

In that case you need to delete the memory there before you add a newly allocated object:

```
if(test == "a"){
            Class2 *c2 = new Class2(param1,param2,param3,param4);
            delete films[i];
            films[i] = c2;
        }


        else if(test == "b"){
            Class3 *c3 = new Class3(param1,param2,param3,param4);
            delete films[i];
            films[i] = c3;
        }


        else {
            Class1 *c1 = new Class1(param1,param2,param3);
            delete films[i];
            films[i] = c1;
        }
```

For this to work however, you need for `films[i]` to be either `NULL` or a valid memory location. If `films[i]` is not initialized and you call delete upon it it will crash. You need to handle that on the parts of the program that I am not seeing at the moment.

Also, it is best to debug and make sure your destructor is being called.

Answer (score 1):

Really I don't understand why people use C++ unless they use features of it. Use vector and delegate the task of destruction automatically.

Use `vector` and read the documentation before you do that.

In case of vector..you can do like this

```
vector<classname> v;
v.push_back( class's object);
```

Comment: I am not allowed to use vector in my task, it is something i forgot to mention, sorry.

Comment: @TamasHargitai edit your question. We can't guess what you want to do.

Comment: There would have to be a lot more involved than just pushing into a `std::vector<classname>` with this, as the OP has a polymorphic derivation hierarchy, and this solution would regress to [object slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-object-slicing).

Comment: I dont know all these name but yes here in this case...an properly hierarchical class would do the trick.  @WhozCraig

Comment: @WhozCraig.: If possible you can suggest me to modify or you can m,odify or wrrite a new answer...anyway it will help me answer this half specified question.

Comment: @coderredoc There really isn't much point to do so, as the OP has made this somewhat irrelevant once they updated their question with the no-vector clause. They can't use `std::vector`, and certainly can't use what would be required to make this a proper [RAII](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/raii) solution (a `std::vector` of some smart pointer type (ex: `std::unique_ptr<baseclass>`) to fulfill the polymorphic requirements.

Comment: @WhozCraig.: Yes it doesn't meet the purpose of OP but atleast would serve the purpose of future users...rest is what you decide...`unique_ptr` is the best the language can offer I would say...hope OP reads these discussion and read accordingly.